# Allow currency sumbols as well as numbers on keypress

Tags: javascript

How can I disallow user to type anything other than number and currency symbol in a textbox?

I have written this much to block user entering alphabets and other symbols.

```
   function blockNonNumbers(obj, e, allowDecimal, allowNegative)
    {
        var key;
        var isCtrl = false;
        var keychar;
        var reg;

        if (window.event) 
        {
            key = e.keyCode;
            isCtrl = window.event.ctrlKey
        }
        else if (e.which)
        {
            key = e.which;
            isCtrl = e.ctrlKey;
        }

        if (isNaN(key))
        {
            return true;
        }

        keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

        // check for backspace or delete, or if Ctrl was pressed
        if (key == 8 || isCtrl)
        {
            return true;
        }

        reg = /\d /;
        var isFirstN = allowNegative ? keychar == '-' && obj.value.indexOf('-') == -1 : false;
        var isFirstD = allowDecimal ? keychar == '.' && obj.value.indexOf('.') == -1 : false;

        return isFirstN || isFirstD;
}
```

But how to allow currency symbol with numbers on keypress?

Comment: What currency symbols?

Comment: Might it be best to search the value of the input, check what character it is, remove it if invalid. Looking for what keys are pressed might be difficult due to keyboard and language inconsistencies.

Comment: Symbols like  ££ signs

Comment: Most currency symbols aren't done by a simple/single keypress/code, e.g my keyboard only allows dollar's , for a euro i need to type 5 keys, more here: http://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/currency-symbol-alt-codes.php  (alt-0128). Did you keep that requirement in mind?

Comment: How many currency symbols would a user need to enter?  If it's just one, make that a `select` then use an HTML5 number input and you're done.